# How to apply woocommerce "place order" limit for a specific product per month

Tags: javascript, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to set a limit on the number of orders a customer can send to a specific product per month on WooCommerce.
The scenario is:
I have a variable product, one feature is free and three features are paid.
I want to limit its free feature.
So that each user (guest or registered) can not place free orders more than 5 times per month.
And when it exceeds the monthly limit, it will show him a message on the checkout page that he can not order the free product and must wait until next month or order the paid product.
I found the following code but I think it is incomplete.

```js
add_filter('woocommerce_is_purchasable', 'preventPurchaseIfOrderLimitReached', 10, 2);

function preventPurchaseIfOrderLimitReached($is_purchasable, $product)
{
    $OrderLimit = 5;
    $productId = $product->get_id();
    $quantityOrderedToday = getOrderAmount($productId);

    if ($quantityOrdered >= $OrderLimit) {
        $is_purchasable = false;
    }

    return $is_purchasable;
}
```

Comment: I always appreciate the smallest help and I know the value of helping. Your answer in that post limit all users, but I want the limits to be applied individually to each user.

Comment: I tried it, I set the $limit to 1 order per week.
But time and time again I was able to place an order. In the next attempt, I changed the $total value and all users were restricted.